# How can I check the status of user x and user x?

Tags: mysql

I am looking for a SELECT query where I can find out the status of two users, status can be multiple things but let's keep it simple and check if both users are friends or not.

Using this query I can select every user that has x status, right now x means no status. But doing so I get the user table returned, I want the return to be true or false. Also, this query returns everyone that has x status with user x. I want to return true or false based on: if user x and x have a status, in this case friends. I hope I am not being to vague here.

```
SELECT 
    u.*
FROM User u
LEFT JOIN User_Status us
    ON u.id = User_ID1
    AND us.User_ID2 = 4
WHERE us.status IS NULL
```

User table:

```
ID-----first_name-----last_name-----etc...<br>**
-2--------James----------someting-------...<br>
-4----------Jack-----------someting-------...<br>
-5--------Sabrina---------someting-------...<br>
```

User_status table:

```
User_ID1-----User_ID2-----Status<br>**
-----------4-----------------2-----friends<br>
-----------2-----------------4-----friends<br>
-----------4-----------------5-----something else<br>
-----------5-----------------4-----something else<br>
```

Wanted result:

```
ID 2 (James) & ID 4 (Jack)
isFriend
true

ID 2 (James) & ID 5 (Sabrina)<br>
isFriend
false (They don't even have a status together.)
```

Comment: In your desired results you have the same IDs but different results...

Comment: Whoops! Fixed...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, your question is a little bit vague. Based on what I've understood, you want to find out if two users (known ID's) are friends or not?

The query below should help you with that.

```
SELECT
    "A_USER_ID" as user_a,
    "B_USER_ID" as user_b,
    (
      CASE 
      WHEN EXISTS(
        SELECT * 
        FROM User_Status us 
        WHERE us.status = "friends" AND ((
            us.User_ID1 = "A_USER_ID" AND us.User_ID2 = "B_USER_ID" 
        ) OR (
            us.User_ID1 = "B_USER_ID" AND us.User_ID2 = "A_USER_ID"
        ))
      )
      THEN "true" 
      ELSE "false" 
      END
   ) as friends
FROM
    User u
WHERE
    u.id = "A_USER_ID";
```

Comment: Your explanation is indeed much better and this is what I am looking for. How ever needing to pass the ID on 7 different places seems kinda strange, is there no way to just input the 2 ID's 1 time?

Comment: Also there is one small problem, if the status between 2 ID's exists but is not == friends. It still says true. I only say false if 2 ID's don't have a status together @mateus

Comment: It still din't work, but I fixed it adding one extra pair of (). Anyway thanks for your help.

Comment: Answering the first comment... Probably there is but I guess you won't be able to do it in a single select (sql operation). The ID's are being used in 7 different places but they are actually necessary in only 4 of them (the inner query), the others are there only to make the result pretty.

Comment: Yeah the thing is, I am using express so it will look something like this: ('query' ? for every var in this case ID), [user1_ID, user2_ID, user1_ID, user2_ID, user1_ID, user2_ID, user1_ID, user2_ID], function () {} etc.

Comment: You could just write a sql function that have the ID's as parameters and returns whether they are friends or not. This would probably be the best way.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/140241/discussion-between-vera-perrone-and-mateus).